# How to skip a merge output in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, merge

I have a problem with a merge clauses in my stored procedure.
In this procedure I do few merges based on JSON, and for each merge operation (I mean insert/update/delete) a output is always generated.
This is not expected, because at the end of procedure I want to return a message depend on some conditions.

Finally the message is never returned, because merge output is being returned.

How to skip presenting the output data from merge?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure] 
@PostData nvarchar(max)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;


                    SELECT
                        JSON_Value (c.value, '$.ID') as ID,
                        JSON_Value (c.value, '$.Name') as ID,
                        JSON_Value (c.value, '$.IsDeleted') as ID,


                        INTO #tempTable FROM OPENJSON (@PostData, '$.MyArray') as c

                        MERGE [dbo].[Table1] AS dst
                        USING (SELECT * from #tempTable) AS src
                        ON dst.ID = src.ID
                        WHEN MATCHED AND #tempTable.IsDeleted = 1 THEN DELETE

                        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Name = #tempTable.Name         

                        WHEN NOT MATCHED AND #tempTable.ID = -1 THEN
                        INSERT(Imie,IsDeleted)
                        VALUES(#tempTable.Name,IsDeleted);



        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;


    END CATCH;

                IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;

                SELECT 'Success' as [Message]
```

Comment: I think you need to post your actual stored procedure code here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: What is the output you don't want to see?

Comment: I've updated my post.
I don't want an output at all.

Comment: Without an `OUTPUT` clause, a `MERGE` isn't going to "output" anything at all (except perhaps an error if it fails, but that's not output in the sense of a result set). Whatever you think your problem is, it's not that. Depending on what you're using to consume this result, you may need a `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of your procedure. Either that, or there's a misbehaving trigger on `Table1` that produces output.

Comment: I understand you don't want any output, but what is the message that you are getting?  Knowing what it is can help us to help you get rid of it.

Comment: is it possible to paste a image here?

Comment: Ok, I found out that output is being generated by trigger. Is there any option to avoid this output?

Comment: Chiefly -- rewrite the trigger to not suck. Triggers should not ever produce result sets, and this is why -- innocent code that doesn't know about the trigger can't avoid getting caught up in it. It breaks most common patterns for updating the table. The ability to return a result set in a trigger is deprecated, so if anyone is arguing they "need" this ability somehow, re-educate them. There's a "workaround", but it's not pretty -- capture the output with `INSERT .. EXEC`. It's much better for the trigger itself to do this, if it *must* do something that produces a result.

Comment: ok, triggger has been rewritten and now everything looks good, thank you guys for helping :)